# Error when saving new PCB project using Altium

Tags: altium

I have Altium Designer V 21.0.9,
When I do ***File -> New -> Project***, then ***create***, it gives me the following error

[image]

Comment: Do you have **access** to the folder "C:\Users\hp\Documents\Altium\New Project\PCB_Project\"?

Comment: @Velvel Yes I guess :) I created a library in that folder couple days ago

Comment: This link will take you, with a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: [https://forum.live.altium.com/](https://forum.live.altium.com/)

Comment: I’m voting to close because this is about a software/computer error which is off-topic.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Thank you but this's not going to work since I don't have valid license.

Comment: @JYelton I'm pretty sure it's an Altium related issue :)

Comment: My mistake: This link will take you, even **without** a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Comment: Altium issue or not, this question is not answerable without a lot of back-and-forth troubleshooting, which is not suitable for a Q&A. It needs to be directed to Altium support or a customer support forum; somewhere you can follow steps like sending in an error log or trying various suggestions.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Thank you so much. Unfortunately, the site keeps saying "Sorry, the forum is not available" and it takes me back to the main page. I tried to create a ticket, but the page also isn't working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to restart the pc and everything works fine.